# mapping keys in secureCRT, emacs

Tags: emacs, ssh, mapping, ssh-keys

I would like to map the key combination `CTRL+Left_Arrow` to `M-b` in SecureCRT for use with Emacs.  I am able to map keys via octal notation but I am not sure what the correct octal notation or method for doing this is for this specific combination.  I am using SecureCRT 6.7.2 on Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: are you running emacs in text-mode within SecureCRT, or are you running SecureCRT in a terminal within emacs?

Comment: I am running SecureCRT connected to a unix machine from my Windows machine.  I have my prompt setup to use emacs editing and therefore want to use the shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out: SecureCRT represents the `meta` key with the string `\e` so to do the thing I wanted to above simply map the key `CTRL+Left_Arrow` to `\eb` and everything works as desired.  The mapping in SecureCRT is done through the menu bar under session options.